# Edit/Update datagridview VB form

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

When I try to edit and update the data in datagriview it comes up with an error message saying Operator '&' is not defined for type 'TextBox' and string "".

please help. Thanks

Here is my code

```
 Private Sub btnaddrecord_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnaddrecord.Click

    Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
    If Not cnn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then

        cnn.Open()
    End If

    cmd.Connection = cnn

    If Me.IdentificationNotest.Tag & "" = "" Then

        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO vehicledefects(Codenumber, vehiclereg, datereported, defects1, repaired1, defects2, repaired2, defects3, repaired3, datefixed) " & _
        " VALUES(" & Me.IdentificationNotest.Text & ",'" & Me.vehiclereg.Text & "','" & Me.datereported.Text & "','" & Me.defects1.Text & "','" & Me.repaired1.Text & "','" & _
        Me.defects2.Text & "','" & Me.repaired2.Text & "','" & _
        Me.defects3.Text & "','" & Me.repaired3.Text & "','" & _
        Me.datefixed.Text & "')"
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Else

        cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE vehicledefects" & _
         " SET Codenumber =" & Me.IdentificationNotest.Text & _
          ", vehiclereg ='" & Me.vehiclereg.Text & "'" & _
            ", datereported ='" & Me.datereported.Text & "'" & _
            ", defects1 ='" & Me.defects1.Text & "'" & _
            ", repaired1 ='" & Me.repaired1.Text & "'" & _
            ", defects2 ='" & Me.defects2.Text & "'" & _
            ", repaired2='" & Me.repaired2.Text & "'" & _
            ", defects3='" & Me.defects3.Text & "'" & _
            ", repaired3='" & Me.repaired3.Text & "'" & _
            ", datefixed='" & Me.datefixed.Text & "'" & _
         " WHERE Codenumber =" & Me.IdentificationNotest.Tag
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End If

    refreshdata()

    Me.btnclear.PerformClick()

    cnn.Close()
    datefixed.Text = ""
    IdentificationNotest.Text = ""

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the future, you should also post the line number the error is being thrown on.

The error is telling you that you're doing something like:

```
dim myString as String = myTextBox & " some more text"
```

in this case, you would need to do:

```
dim myString as String = myTextBox.Text & " some more text"
```

In the code you posted, I wasn't able to find an instance of this - so perhaps its somewhere else in the code. Though, the code was hard to read so I may have missed it.

You may also be aware that this code is susceptible to [SQL Injection attacks](http://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: Have you stepped through the code in debugger mode to see the values that are being concatenated? In debug mode you can hover over each item to see the value.

Comment: everything seems to be fine. not sure whether having a generated value of 8 digits input into the datagrid via form entry would create this error?

Comment: At this point it's just typical debugging techniques. Break it down into smaller pieces. Build up the string one item at a time and see when it errors.